# How to access custom module with normal user in odoo

Tags: odoo

I created a custom module and created a new user in odoo with email :1@1.com and password :1234 .When i try to login with new user webpage show this error

> :"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application."

and in eclipe show this error:

> "AccessError: ('AccessError', u'Sorry, you are not allowed to access
>   this document. Only users with the following access level are
>   currently allowed to do that:\n- Human Resources/Employee\n\t-
>   Administration/Settings\n\n(Document model: ir.ui.menu)')"

. Below is my code :
Core.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv 
class Student(osv.osv):
    _name = "tt.student" 
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Code',size=20,required=True), 
        'ten': fields.char('Name',size=100,required=True),
        'ngay':fields.date('Date',required=True),
    }
Student()
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>  
    <record id="student_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Student</field>
        <field name="model">tt.student</field> 
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                        <field string="Mã số" name="name"/> 
                        <field string="Tên" name="ten"/>
                        <field string="Ngày sinh" name="ngay"/>
                </tree> 
         </field>
    </record>
    <record id="student_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Student</field>
        <field name="model">tt.student</field> 
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <group col="2">
                        <field string="Mã số" name="name"/> 
                        <field string="Tên" name="ten"/>
                        <field string="Ngày sinh" name="ngay"/>
                    </group>
                </form> 
         </field>
    </record>
    <record id="action_student" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Student</field>
            <field name="res_model">tt.student</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field> 
    </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <menuitem id="main" name="Student"></menuitem>
            <menuitem id="quanly" name="Quản lý" parent="main"></menuitem>
                <menuitem id="sinhvien_sub" action="action_student" name="Sinh viên" parent="quanly"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add in the security folder the access. Add ir.access.csv file and you should define for each object the access to view, read, write and delete.